# Firebase storage security rules OR not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to read this image:
Avisos/GUinz0Tx8RQl8GUAixwx/fondo1.jpg

the rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /negocios/{negocioId}{
      match /Avisos/{avisoID}/{allPaths=**}  {
          allow read: if request.auth != null && 
          (
            isOwner(firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)).data.uid_nagusia) ||      
            (firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)/empleados/$(request.auth.uid)).data.avisos_leer == true) ||
            request.auth.uid in firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)/Avisos/$(avisoID)).data.empleados
              );
          
          allow create: if request.auth != null && 
            request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024 && (
            firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)).data.uid_nagusia == request.auth.uid ||
            firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)/empleados/$(request.auth.uid)).data.avisos_crear == true
              );
      }
    }

    function isOwner(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to read like this in Angular with user SqfiHvKyXRatkE3WInm2k7XkcLL2:

```
const path =`negocios/3xPJtdaSnZZtJ2t1WY69/Avisos/GUinz0Tx8RQl8GUAixwx/fondo1.jpg
    const ref = this.FirebaseStorage.ref(path);
file1 = await ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise();
```

the document of avisos ("GUinz0Tx8RQl8GUAixwx") has this array:

```
empleados: ["SqfiHvKyXRatkE3WInm2k7XkcLL2"]
```

in this case the field "avisos_leer" is false
`/negocios/3xPJtdaSnZZtJ2t1WY69/empleados/SqfiHvKyXRatkE3WInm2k7XkcLL2`

And in the document uid_nagusia is "BQcruUKDV8X0PSrKputY6RJGcbh2"
`negocios/3xPJtdaSnZZtJ2t1WY69`

The user is in the array "empleados" of the document, so the last condition is true (not first and second). This not work but if i remove the first or second condition, works. It seems like 2 conditions returning "false" don't check the 3rd

Just changing the order of the conditions works. I have put the last one (The one that is true) in second position and it works. But if the user is not uid_nagusia and it is not in the array but he has "avisos_leer" true, it does not work because the third condition is not checked.

```
isOwner(firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)).data.uid_nagusia) ||

request.auth.uid in firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)/Avisos/$(avisoID)).data.empleados ||

(firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)/empleados/$(request.auth.uid)).data.avisos_leer == true)
```

Comment: If i remove the first condition and and I keep the second and the third works... It seems like 2 conditions returning "false" don't check the 3rd.

Comment: You're referencing a variable `negocioId` but you're not showing where it's defined.

Comment: The rules is inside of abtoher path:match /negocios/{negocioId}

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete set of relevant rules along with the data involved so we can try to run them for ourselves.

Comment: Sorry, i have done

Comment: Please share the relevant **app code** and **database data**.  We should be able to take what you have and run it for ourselves. The rules by themselves don't do anything without those details.

Comment: I think that with what I just put, there is all the necessary information. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that if any of the conditions generates an error before something evaluates true, the entire rule will be immediately rejected and will not continue with any more checks.  Only a real boolean "false" value will let the rule continue with the next condition. It's easier to examine errors if you're using the local rules emulator - you won't be able to see them in the console for live queries.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, the same rules work in firestore to display the document information (With the same order)

Answer (score 0):

pleas try the following and let me know the result;

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /negocios/{negocioId}{
      match /Avisos/{avisoID}/{allPaths=**}  {
          allow read: if request.auth != null && isOwner(firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)).data.uid_nagusia);
              
          allow read: if  request.auth != null && (firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)/empleados/$(request.auth.uid)).data.avisos_leer == true)
          
          allow read: if  request.auth != null &&  request.auth.uid in firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)/Avisos/$(avisoID)).data.empleados
          
          allow create: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024 && (firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)).data.uid_nagusia == request.auth.uid);
          
          allow create: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024 &&(firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(negocioId)/empleados/$(request.auth.uid)).data.avisos_crear == true)
      }
    }

    function isOwner(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: still not work, only changing the positions

Comment: and did you check the given user have all the require privileges to pass the rules ?if not then please cross check it.